# How do I make gsea plot with group names labelled?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, bioinformatics

I am trying to plot gsea similar to image as given below:
[image: Gsea Image]

the [tutorial](https://bioconductor.org/packages/devel/bioc/vignettes/fgsea/inst/doc/fgsea-tutorial.html) does not give you such plots. So I tried the [github](https://github.com/NicolasH2/gggsea) link.
But it failed to generate the similar plot

Comment: What do you mean by "group names labelled"?

Comment: @zx8754 here the group names are `Splenic volume > 194` and `Splenic volume >= 194`

Answer (score 0):

I checked both gseaplot2{enrichplot} and plotEnrichment{fgsea} and found no options to automatically add the group names. It might be a good idea to just add the names after exporting to Adobe Illustrator. Would be happy to hear other ideas though if anyone else knows a better way.